# ¿Como puedo sumar 2 fechas datetime formato YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn]?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Con esto he llegado a sumar solo minutos pero me piden tambien segundos

```
 select msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(h.run_date,h.run_time) as 'DT_FECHA_INICIO',  
 dateadd(minute,((h.run_duration/10000*3600 + (h.run_duration/100)%100*60 + h.run_duration%100 
 + 31 )
 / 60), msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(h.run_date,h.run_time)) as 'DT_FECHA_FIN' from etc.tabla
```

Comment: Las fechas no se suman. ¿Cuanto es el 3 de julio más el 12 de agosto? ¿Qué datos tiene cada columna?

Comment: [ésto](https://www.kyocode.com/2018/05/sumar-o-restar-dias-a-una-fecha-en-sql-server/) podría ayudarte

Comment: Cuál es el resultado esperado de sumar dos fechas para tu caso? Plantéalo como un ejemplo mínimo, con eso podemos ayudar